# Better to use two dedicated applications-clients or one for both services if that client exists for Bitbucket and GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, bitbucket, github-for-windows, atlassian-sourcetree

What tools can I use to also work with bitbucket and github using the same software-client on my computer? Is it possible? Maybe is a better solution would be to install the Bitbucket SourceTree application for Bitbucket and GitHub applications for GitHub?

Comment: The standard `git` command line app? Any git application should be able to use any git repository, wherever it's hosted.

Comment: Not command line app but with GUI some application. For example can I use TortoiseHG for Bitbucket and GitHub without any problems?

Comment: @mczaplicki, any tool that supports multiple [`remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html)s should work.

Comment: TortoiseGit would be a better choice. But yes, of course you can. In the end, it's git, with remote git repos. You don't use chrome to access google.com, and Firefox to access mozilla.com, do you? Same with git.